# ciphertext is too short when using laravel/passport

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-passport, mcrypt, libsodium

Can anyone help with a problem I'm getting with setting up laravel/passport?

I've currently got the granting clients access to user data sorted and it's storing auth_codes in the DB fine.

However, when going to POST http://my-app.test/oauth/token to retrieve access tokens I'm getting the following response.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.",
    "hint": "Cannot decrypt the authorization code",
    "message": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."
}
```

I'm sending through the following params

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:3
client_secret:TYSRJyZAGeSAnzFYyYKAp5F15C4EJiea4V5oamm2
redirect_ui:http://my-app.test/callback
code:5f2d0685414689cc322d10e5ada221e020d00036b1f9fe4154e5578511ed2a51373aa187142a96f2
```

A bit of digging through passport, I've tracked down that the defuse/php-encryption package is throwing the following error:

> Ciphertext is too short

Could this be related & what should I do to solve that if so? I've attempted with both sodium/mcrypt php extensions.

Comment: See this if helps https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard

Comment: @Dilek Thanks, unfortunately the setup I am going for requires the use of an OAuth2 setup.

Comment: Yes, with what you showed! Showing full codes would get more helps from people I think.